# Why is the merge-sort taking too much time to sort?

Tags: java, sorting

I've been trying to optimize this mergesort version but it takes too long to sort around 3 million of registers. Where am I doing it wrong? I would appreciate some help, thanks.

Persona is a class that has a string and an Integer, just in case that you guys want to know in order to help me.

```
public class Mergesort {
  private ArrayList<Persona> numbers = new ArrayList();
  private  ArrayList<Persona> helper;
  private int number;
  private boolean ascending;


  public void sort(ArrayList<Persona> values, boolean ascending) {
    this.numbers = values;
    this.ascending = ascending;
    number = values.size();
    helper = new ArrayList();
    mergesort(0, number - 1);
  }

  /**
   * Determines the middle of the array to sort the left side and the right side 
   * Then it merges both arrays.
   * @param low
   * @param high 
   */
  private void mergesort(int low, int high) {
    // check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
    if (low < high) {
      // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
      int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
      // Sort the left side of the array
      mergesort(low, middle);
      // Sort the right side of the array
      mergesort(middle + 1, high);
      // Combine them both
      merge(low, middle, high);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Merges the arrays.
   * @param low
   * @param middle
   * @param high 
   */
  private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

    // Copy both parts into the helper array
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
          helper.add(i, numbers.get(i));
    }

    int i = low;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = low;
    // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
    // to the original array
    while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
      if ( helper.get(i).id  <= helper.get(j).id) {
        numbers.set(k, helper.get(i));
        i++;
      } else {
        numbers.set(k,helper.get(j));
        j++;
      }
      k++;
    }
    // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
    while (i <= middle) {
      numbers.set(k,helper.get(i));
      k++;
      i++;
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Define long. What are you comparing against?

Comment: More than 4 minutes.

Comment: I haven't seen the sorted array yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never clear out the contents of `helper` (which should not be a global anyawy), which means each time you are merging more and more data.  I'm really surprised you didn't get out-of-memory.

Comment: `helper` should be a local variable in `merge()`, recreated on each invocation.  However, I haven't thoroughly debugged your code for other errors.  The use of `helper` seems suspect.

Comment: If I do that, I get an java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: That's because you shouldn't be using `helper.add(i, numbers.get(i))`.  In fact, you'd probably be better off writing `helper = new ArrayList<Persona>(numbers.subList(low, high))`.

Comment: Still have the same issue.

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: The best suggestion is for you to trace through your code in an IDE debugger, such as Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA.  You can then determine exactly what is going on. This is a basic part of developing software and if you haven't yet learned how to do it, now is a good time to start.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code running and the o/p is alryt?
In the merge function there must be another loop,after the first while loop. The first while loop terminated because either j>high or i>middle. You just wrote j>high condition,dere is no i>middle condtn.After that loop thre must be something like dis

```
if(j>high)
{
while (i <= middle) {
      numbers.set(k,helper.get(i));
      k++;
      i++;
    }
}
else
{
while (j <= high) {
      numbers.set(k,helper.get(j));
      k++;
      j++;
    }
}
```

N clear the helper